# How to loop through a specific row of a 2-dimensional Array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, multidimensional-array

I have 2-dimensional array and I would like to inspect each element in a specific row with If-Then statements and assign assign values to the next row depending on the outcome of the If-Then statements? What is the correct syntax for looping through the elements of a row in a 2-d array?

Comment: What is the excel connection to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try using the next `Sub`:

```
Sub changeRow(arr As Variant, iR As Long, strTxt As String)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) '(arr, 2) to determine the number of columns
        arr(iR, i) = arr(iR, i) & strTxt
    Next i
End Sub
```

Of course, it can be designed to do whatever you need on the respective row. Even extending parameters to be used.

It can easily be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testIterate2DArrayRow()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, arrR, iRow As Long, strAdd As String
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   iRow = 2          'the array row to be iterated
   strAdd = " - XX"  'string to be added to each row element (instructional example)
   arr = sh.Range("A2:D6").value           'the easiest way to create a 2D array
    arrR = Application.Index(arr, iRow, 0) 'create a 1D slice of the row to be iterated/modified
                                           'if you need only iterating to extract something, you may stop here
                                           'and iterate between its elements...
    Debug.Print Join(arrR, "|")            'just to visually see the row content
   changeRow arr, iRow, strAdd             'iterate on the iRow row (and modify something)
   Debug.Print Join(Application.Index(arr, iRow, 0), "|") 'visual evidence of the modification...
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

I will let the above code for other people liking to learn the general concept.

Please, test the next code, which should process the array as (I understood) you need.

Its first lines only create the opportunity to easily check the concept. So, you should place the necessary bays on an Excel sheet, from "A1" to "J1" and run the above code. It will return the processed array starting from "L1":

```
Sub analizeBays()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, BayRay(), i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  BayRay = sh.Range("A1:J4").value 'only to easily test the concept
  
  For i = LBound(BayRay, 2) To UBound(BayRay, 2)
        If BayRay(1, i) <= 10 Then
           BayRay(2, i) = 2035
           BayRay(3, i) = 2005
           BayRay(4, i) = 1005
        ElseIf BayRay(1, i) > 10 And BayRay(1, i) <= 12 Then
           BayRay(2, i) = 2022
           BayRay(3, i) = 1032
           BayRay(4, i) = 4344
        End If
  Next i
  'drop the processed array content starting from "L1")
  sh.Range("L1").Resize(UBound(BayRay), UBound(BayRay, 2)).value = BayRay
End Sub
```

Comment: So I have 10 Bays each of a specific length and I need to assign 3 unique identifiers for each bay depending on the length of each bay. So I have BayRay(1 to 4, 1 to 10) As Variant I need to look at all the values in the 1st row and then use this If-Then Statement to assign unique identifiers to the 3 rows below. If Bayi <= 10, Then BayRay(2,i) = 2035 BayRay(3,i) = 2005 BayRay(4,i) = 1005 ElseIf Bayi > 10 And Bayi <= 12 Then BayRay(2,i) = 2022 BayRay(3,i) = 1032 BayRay(4,i) = 4344

Comment: @questions I am trying to get you... What are the 'Bays' you are mentioning? For my English skills, they are places where ships anchor... **Strings**?  If yes, do you want counting each element number of digits and based on that, do something? Is that what you try explaining?

Comment: @questions Basically, after clarifying what these 'Bays' are, you need iterating between a specific array row and according to 'some conditions` modify the correspondent column on the rows bellow. Should be this understanding correct? Can you give o relevant example of such a 'bay' representation?

Comment: No bays in this instance are divisions in a building the space between each truss is considered a bay and I have a userform in which the user inputs the length of each bay (10',11',14',16' etc.) I have 3 different components that will be used in each bay and each of these components come in several lengths and each specific component of specific length is identified with a unique identifier we can call these items. I need to inspect the length of each bay and assign the appropriate items to be used for each bay. Make more sense?

Comment: @questions Yes, a little more... Now, are  these bay values shown exactly as you type them? I mean `10'`  or `10"` would not be considered  values, for VBA they are strings.  But, if I know (**exactly**) the terminal character (' or"), I can extract the value. Now, is it clear what I try explaining?

Comment: No they are integer values 10,11,12,14,16. Yes I understand where you are coming from now.

Comment: @questions OK. I will edit my answer and place a specific solution for what (I understood) you need. The posted one is general, to iterate on **any** array row... Not right now, but soon. I have to finish something urgent...

Comment: @questions Please, test the code I pasted after '**Edited**:' and send some feedback. Like checking algorithm I tried using the one you posted above...

Comment: "resizing processed array content" what is this part about?

Comment: @questions You can drop an array content in a range **only if the range to receive it has the same number of rows and columns as the array in discussion**.  So, starting from "L1", an enlarged range having the array number of rows (`UBound(BayRay)`) and its number of columns (`UBound(BayRay, 2)` waits for the array content to be dropped...  But doesn't the above solution answer your question?

Comment: Oh yes that is exactly what I needed thank you very much

Comment: @questions I like to remind you that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the suggested solution works...

Comment: Where do I make it an accepted answer

Comment: @questions On the left side of the about answer it is a check box to be checked...

Comment: Ok I have a new question I would like to do the same thing but for the other side of my building (opposite side) I was wondering how hard it would be to have a 3 dimensional array BayRay(1 to 5, 1 to 10, 1 to 2) the last index being each side of the building. Then if the other side is different it would be accounted as opposed to just multiplying the results by 2 1 for each side of the building. I am over my head trying to find a solution with this additional index/dimension or could this be done quite simply.

Comment: @questions I am driving now... When I will have access to my laptop I will try helping, but I would like to state that the community rules state that for "a new question" you **must** place another question... Copy the code I supplied (to not risk your question to be closed) and clearly explain what you want doing this time. If you tag me (here: @FaneDuru), placing the link to the question, I will show you how you can proceed, if in the meantime nobody already answered your question...

Answer (score 1):

### Loop Through a Row of a 2D Array

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughRow()
    
    Const RowIndex As Long = 2
    Const Criteria As Double = 3
    Const MinNum As Long = 1
    Const MaxNum As Long = 5
    
    ' Populate with random integers.
    
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 5, 1 To 5)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        For c = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
            Data(r, c) = Int((MaxNum - MinNum + 1) * Rnd + MinNum)
        Next c
    Next r
    
    ' Write criteria row.
    
    For c = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
        If Data(RowIndex, c) > Criteria Then
            Data(RowIndex + 1, c) = "Yes"
        Else
            Data(RowIndex + 1, c) = "No"
        End If
    Next c
    
    ' Print result.

    Debug.Print "Column", "Row " & RowIndex, "Row " & RowIndex + 1
    For c = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
        Debug.Print c, Data(RowIndex, c), Data(RowIndex + 1, c)
    Next c

End Sub
```